# Framebox and subfigure with dirtree package

Tags: subcaption, dirtree

I've integrated `dirtree` package in my manuscript but having issues with the following.

1. Framebox: I consistently frame all figures in my manuscript using `\framebox`, however, applying this to dirtree output messes things up. How do I get past this?
2. Subfigure: I cannot seem to align 3 figures (Figure 2a, 2b & 2c) on the same horizontal line; I am basically trying to replicate [this example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions). What am I doing wrong here?

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox[\textwidth]{%
\dirtree{%
.1 \textbf{NDLTD}.
.2 \textbf{OCLC}.
.3 \vdots.
.3 x.xml.
.3 \vdots.
}
}
\caption{How do I frame dirtree-generated figures}
\label{fig:minimal-example:frame-dirtree}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
\dirtree{%
.1 \textbf{NDLTD}.
.2 \textbf{OCLC}.
.3 \vdots.
.3 x.xml.
.3 \vdots.
}
\caption{dirtree1}
\label{fig:dirtree1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
\dirtree{%
.1 \textbf{NDLTD}. 
.2 \textbf{OCLC}. 
.3 \textbf{2010}. 
.4 \vdots. 
.4 x.xml. 
.4 \vdots. 
.3 \vdots. 
}
\caption{dirtree2}
\label{fig:dirtree2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
\dirtree{%
.1 \textbf{NDLTD}. 
.2 \textbf{OCLC}. 
.3 \textbf{2010}. 
.4 \textbf{z}. 
.5 \vdots. 
.5 x.xml. 
.5 \vdots. 
.3 \vdots. 
}
\caption{dirtree3}
\label{fig:dirtree3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Combined dirtree structures}\label{fig:dirtrees}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the exact width of a dirtree, because it's typeset in a box as wide as the current text width by design. Also `\centering` confuses it, so it's best to typeset it in a `minipage`.

Comment: @egreg Tried typesetting all 3 sub-figures into seperate `minipage` environments --still no luck with placing them on one horizontal line.

Comment: Don't leave blank lines between the `subfigure` environments. A width of 3cm seems good for the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `\framebox` command around a `minipage` environment as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
  \dirtree{%
  .1 \textbf{NDLTD}.
  .2 \textbf{OCLC}.
  .3 \vdots.
  .3 x.xml.
  .3
  \vdots.
  }
\end{minipage}
}
\caption{Framing a dirtree-generated figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

For your subfigures, the only real problem is that you have left a blank line (causing a paragraph break) between the environments.  Removing these and making them sligtly wider gives:

[image: subfigure output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\dirtree{%
.1 \textbf{NDLTD}.
.2 \textbf{OCLC}.
.3 \vdots.
.3 x.xml.
.3 \vdots.
}
\caption{dirtree1}
\label{fig:dirtree1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\dirtree{%
.1 \textbf{NDLTD}. 
.2 \textbf{OCLC}. 
.3 \textbf{2010}. 
.4 \vdots. 
.4 x.xml. 
.4 \vdots. 
.3 \vdots. 
}
\caption{dirtree2}
\label{fig:dirtree2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\dirtree{%
.1 \textbf{NDLTD}. 
.2 \textbf{OCLC}. 
.3 \textbf{2010}. 
.4 \textbf{z}. 
.5 \vdots. 
.5 x.xml. 
.5 \vdots. 
.3 \vdots. 
}
\caption{dirtree3}
\label{fig:dirtree3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Combined dirtree structures}\label{fig:dirtrees}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for this --minipage worked like a charm. I am still struggling with #2 (using `subcaption` to place `dirtree` outputs on single line) though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to upload that part.  Added now.